# How to make my logic circuit drawn by circuitikz look nicer?

Tags: circuitikz, technical-drawing, logic

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} \draw
  (0,3) node[not port] (mynot1) {}
  (mynot1.in) node[anchor=east] {$r$}
  (mynot1.out) node[anchor=south] {$\neg r$}
  (0,1) node[not port] (mynot2) {}
  (mynot2.in) node[anchor=east] {$q$}
  (mynot2.out) node[anchor=south] {$\neg q$}
  (3,4) node[and port] (myand1) {}
  (myand1.in 1) node[anchor=east] {$p$}
  (myand1.out) node[anchor=west] {$p \wedge \neg r$}
  (3,0) node[and port] (myand2) {}
  (myand2.in 2) node[anchor=east] {$r$}
  (myand2.out) node[anchor=west] {$\neg q \wedge r$}
  (mynot1.out) -| (myand1.in 2)
  (mynot2.out) -| (myand2.in 1)
  (5,2) node[or port] (myor) {}
  (myor.out) node[anchor=west] {$(p \wedge \neg r) \vee (\neg q \wedge r)$}
  (myand1.out) |- (myor.in 1)
  (myand2.out) |- (myor.in 2)
;\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

The above is how I draw my logic circuit by using package circuitikz.  I can basically figure out how to draw the circuit but it looks ugly, see

[image]

1) I want it to look nicer, i.e. smaller "not" gate, colored label text, more compact in positioning, arrowheads on the input and output, etc. just like the style of this: 
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: ok I just replaced the code snippet with a complete tex file.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a first approach to a smaller logic circuit, with more compact positioning, and colored label text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[every label/.style={blue}]
\draw
% draw And1 gate with label then Not1 gate with label
(3,3) node[and port] (myand1) {}
    (-1,3.3) node[label=left:$p$] {} -- (myand1.in 1) 
    (myand1.out)  node[label=right:$p \wedge \neg r$] {}
(0,2.75) node[scale=0.7,not port] (mynot1) {}
    (-1,2.75)node[label=left:$r$] {} -- (mynot1.in) 
    (mynot1.out)    node[label=above:$\neg r$] {}
    (mynot1.out) -- (myand1.in 2)
% draw And2 gate with label then Not2 gate with label
(3,1) node[and port] (myand2) {}
    (-1,0.75) node[label=left:$r$] {} -- (myand2.in 2)
    (myand2.out)  node[label=right:$\neg q \wedge r$] {}
(0,1.3) node[scale=0.7,not port] (mynot2) {}
    (-1,1.3) node[label=left:$q$] {} -- (mynot2.in)
    (mynot2.out)    node[label=above:$\neg q$] {}
    (mynot2.out) -- (myand2.in 1)
% draw Or gate with inputs and output label
(6,2) node[or port] (myor) {}
    (myand1.out) |- (myor.in 1)
    (myand2.out) |- (myor.in 2)
    (myor.out) -- (8,2) node[label=above:$(p \wedge \neg r) \vee (\neg q \wedge r)$] {}
;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need, the one last missing part is the arrowheads on the input and output.

Comment: any updates? :)